# Is the CSS property appearance: none a valid tool for hiding checkboxes style?

Tags: html, css, checkbox

I've been looking for a way to restyle checkboxes using icons no matter where the label is or whether it's present or not. In the end I found https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/appearance
And it looks like `appearance: none` works for both Firefox and Chrome, but I read it's been removed from the **CSS 3 specification** but it's still present in the **CSS Basic User Interface Module Level 4**, caniuse reports this being supported by essentially all major browsers https://caniuse.com/css-appearance .
So my question is can I safely use `appearance: none` for customizing checkboxes or am I at risk of having browser incompatibilities or having it being changed/removed in a not so distant future?

Comment: This is not a question for stackOverFlow. Try the side of esotericism

Comment: Where did you read that it's been removed? I can't find that.